# Where can I find the text of "Prayer" by Father Faber?

Tags: catholicism, church-history

I'm reading a book from the 1920's that mentions Father Faber's book "Prayer" as a good reference on the two main forms of contemplation in the 15th century.  It claims that "Prayer" was then available in any Catholic book shop, but searching today I find no references to it.  Has this text been collected in some other compilation of Faber's writing, or is there a catalog for this kind of text that I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be referring to:

- Faber, Frederick William & John Fitzpatrick, O.M.I. 1920. [*Prayer: Selections from Father Faber*](https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/32003756). London: Burns Oates & Washbourne.

You can find it in a library near you by clicking the above link.

[Chequamegon Books (Washburn, WI, U.S.A.)](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=3876794627) has a copy of it for purchase, only $10.